# Помогите доработать SQL запрос

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день. Есть задание "During the last week, how many clicks did Collective Travellers have in all of its active hotels?"

Для него составлен запрос

```
SELECT
   SUM(qaapplicant.hotel_clickout_lastweek.clickout)
FROM qaapplicant.hotel_clickout_lastweek

JOIN qaapplicant.partner_hotel
  ON qaapplicant.partner_hotel.hotel_id = qaapplicant.hotel_clickout_lastweek.hotel_id

  JOIN qaapplicant.hotel
  ON qaapplicant.hotel.hotel_id = qaapplicant.hotel_clickout_lastweek.hotel_id

  WHERE partner_id =  "p002"
  AND status = 1;
```

Проблема состоит в том, что сейчас я считаю всю сумму `qaapplicant.hotel_clickout_lastweek.clickout`, а требуется считать только `MAX` значения для `qaapplicant.hotel_clickout_lastweek.clickout`. 
Поясняю, в табличке `hotel_clickout_lastweek` есть 2 столбца (`hotel_id` и `clickout`) и для одного `hotel_id` могут быть разные `clickout` и брать мне нужно максимальное.

Comment: из задачи не ясно ровным счетом ничего. из текста на английском понятно только что надо узнать сколько кликов сделали какие то "коллективные путешественники", во всех "активных отелях" за последнюю неделю. Но вот как получить именно "коллективных" и чем они отличаются от "не коллективных", а так же чем отличается "активный" отель от "не активного" не ясно. И не ясно зачем вам понадобился некий максимум, исходя из текста задачи ни о каком максимуме там речи не идет. Видимо надо получить только последнюю неделю в where, определить "коллективных" и "активные" после чего сделать group by и sum

Comment: Извините за неполную инфу по задаче. Вопрос уже решен.